# Bad request when trying to post to rest service with byte[] input

Tags: c#, rest, post

I have tried posting so many different ways, but havent got any further. The solution i am at now returns the following error message:

> The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The
>   expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml'; 'Json'. This can
>   be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the
>   binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more
>   details.

RestService method:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "UploadUser/{sessionID}/{Name}")]
    [OperationContract(Name = "UploadUser")]
    string UploadUser(string sessionID, string name, byte[] image);
```

Trying to post to the service:

```
 client = new HttpClient();
 client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));

 public async Task<string> SaveUserItemAsync(User item, bool isNewItem = false)
 {
     try
     {
         var RestUrl = "http://192.168.240.127:55642/RestServiceImpl.svc/UploadUser/{0}/{1}";

         var uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl, item.Id, item.Name));

         var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Thumbnail, 0, item.Thumbnail.Length);
         var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(base64String);   
         var messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonStr);     

         var cont = new ByteArrayContent(messageBytes);
         cont.Headers.ContentType= MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain");
         //also tried cont.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

         //also tried sending it as stringcontent
         //var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Thumbnail);
         //var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");              

         //also tried multipartcontent with no luck
         //var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
         //multipartContent.Add(cont, "image");

         if (isNewItem)
         {

            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, cont).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
               return res;
               Debug.WriteLine(@"User successfully saved.");

            }
        }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

     }
}
```

when using cont.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

i get another errormessage:

> Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'UploadUser'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body.
>   Expected to find an attribute with name 'type' and value 'object'.
>   Found value 'string'.

Wireshark shows this:

[image: wireshark packet]

Changed method of sending to this:

```
 var senderPackage = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>
                {
                    {"image", messageBytes}
                };               
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(senderPackage);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

with new error:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:image. The InnerException message was 'There was
>   an error deserializing the object of type System.Byte[]. End element
>   'image' from namespace '' expected. Found text
>   'Ii85ai80QUFRU2taSlJnQUJBUUFBQVFBQkFBRC8yd0JEQUJzU0ZCY1VFUnNYRmhjZUhCc2dLRUlyS0NVbEtGRTZQVEJDWUZWbFpGOVZYVnRxZUptQmFuR1FjMXRkaGJXR2tKNmpxNjJyWjRDOHlicW14NW1vcTZULzJ3QkRBUndlSGlnaktFNHJLMDZrYmwxdXBLU2twS1NrcEtTa3BLU2twS1NrcEtTa3BLU2twS..

And Wireshark packet looks like this:

[image: jsondictionarypic]

If someone figures out how to get this to work i will forever be in your debt ;)

Comment: WORKING SOLUTION:  var json = "{ \"image\": [" + string.Join(",", item.Thumbnail) + "] }";

 var content = new StringContent(json);
 content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
 var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Endt up getting it to work by creating my own DataContract and sending it as a stream instead. Inserting code incase anyone ends up having the same trouble i did.

```
[DataContract]
    public class UploadObject
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "image")]
        public byte[] image { get; set; }

    }
```

Rest Service Method:

```
  [OperationContract(Name = "UploadUser")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "UploadUser/{sessionID}/{Name}")]
        string UploadUser(string sessionID, string name, Stream image);
```

Posting to rest:

```
public async Task<string> SaveUserItemAsync(User item, bool isNewItem = false)
        {
            try
            {
                var RestUrl = "http://192.168.240.127:55642/RestServiceImpl.svc/UploadUser/{0}/{1}";

                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl, item.Id, item.Name));
                UploadObject obj = new UploadObject();
                obj.image = item.Thumbnail;

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

                var content = new StreamContent(stream);
                content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;

                if (isNewItem)
                {

                    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                        return res;                       
                    }

                    return "success";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return "Failure";
        }
```

After some days the service started complaining about that it could not take multiple parameters along with stream input, so i changed it back to receive the bytearray and managed to get it working by creating my own jason with formatting the bytearray this way:

```
 var json = "{ \"image\": [" + string.Join(",", item.Thumbnail) + "] }";

 var content = new StringContent(json);
 content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
 var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "application/json" as the media type in your request header for JSON.

Try:

- cont.Headers.ContentType= MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
- `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` to your `interface`
- The body should contain a key 'image' with value as list of bytes.

  ```
   1. Make a dictionary with key "image" and with value array of bytes. 
   2. Serialize the dictionary to Json
   3. Use StringContent insead of ByteArray Content
  ```

Comment: Yes, im not sure how to do that, but i tried adding it as  
var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multipartContent.Add(cont, "image");
And that did not work.. How am i supposed to link array to "image"?

Comment: Also tried changing BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, but that did not work either

Comment: can you post your json string

Comment: updated question with new wireshark image of package

Comment: Your value seems to be a string, it has to be a byte array

Comment: It is a byte array.. Even tried this now:   
var senderPackage = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>
                {
                    {"image", item.Thumbnail}
                };
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(senderPackage);
                var msgBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                var content = new ByteArrayContent(msgBytes);
                content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

Same error :(